# Having trouble with my C++ program. Involes resizing an integer array dynamically

Tags: c++, arrays, function, pointers, dynamic

Here is what I have so far: http://cpp.sh/54vn3

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int *reSIZE(int *&original, int &SIZE, const int &maxSIZE); //function prototype resize
void sortFUNC(int *&original, int &SIZE, const int &maxSIZE); //function prototype sortFUNC

int main()
{
    int SIZE = 4; //size of current array
    int maxSIZE = 10; //size of final array
    int *original = new int[SIZE] {5, 7, 3, 1}; //old(current) array

    cout << "Elements in array: "; //test output
    reSIZE(original, SIZE, maxSIZE); //call function resize
    cout << endl << endl; //blank line
    cout << "Elements in array in increasing order: "; //test output
    sortFUNC(original, SIZE, maxSIZE); //call function sortFUNC
    cout << endl << endl;
    return 0;
}

int *reSIZE(int *&original, int &SIZE, const int &maxSIZE)//function definition
{
    int *temporiginal = new int[SIZE + 3]; //(final)new array

    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) //copy old array to new array
    {
        temporiginal[i] = original[i];
        cout << original[i] << setw(3);
    }

    delete[] original; //delete old array
    original = temporiginal; //point old array to new array
    return temporiginal;
}

void sortFUNC(int *&original, int &SIZE, const int &maxSIZE)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        int smallest = original[i];
        int smallestINDEX = i;

        for (int m = i; m < SIZE; m++)
        {
            if (original[m] < smallest)
            {
                smallest = original[m];
                smallestINDEX = m;
            }
        }

        swap(original[i], original[smallestINDEX]);
    }

    int *temporiginal = new int[SIZE + 3];

    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        temporiginal[i] = original[i];
        cout << original[i] << setw(3);
    }

    delete[] original;
    original = temporiginal;
}
```

I want to add a few elements at the end of the array in main, but when I do, the program crashes when I run it. The resize function that I created is supposed to expand the function in main to hold 10 elements. The one in main originally holds 4. The new array is supposed to change that to 10. How do I add three more integers to the array in main without it crashing? Is my resize function wrong? Or is it a problem in my main? The program that is shown right now works as is. But when I add another integer in the array in main, it crashes. Like, if I add a 2 after the 1.

Thanks.

Edit: I was able to add elements at the end of the array in main by adding them in the resize function.

cpp.sh/35mww

Like mentioned earlier, maxSIZE isn't being used. There are more useless stuff as well. I have to clean this up, but I figured out what I was trying to figure out. I don't know how to use structures yet. I know that there are a lot of different ways to write a program. I'm just a beginner.

Thanks, everyone.

Comment: You should be consistent with your variable names.

Comment: Can you show the version that crashes?

Comment: Note that you're completely ignoring the `maxSIZE` argument in your resize function (it always makes the array 3 elements bigger). You also have at least one memory leak. And the move at the end of the sort function pretty much does nothing.

Comment: And when you used your debugger to execute your program, one line at a time, and examine the values of all variables on each step, so that you can observe exactly how your program executes and why it does what it does, what observations did you make as to the reason your program crashes?

Comment: Why aren't you using `std::vector<int>`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify the value of size everytime you call the function rezise other wise even if u call the function resize 3 times u always will have SIZE+3 on your array size.After call resize try

```
original[4] = 0;
original[5] = 0;
original[6] = 0;
```

and after that try to do this.

```
   original[7] = 0;
```

you should be able to see your mistake